# Expected value in coin flipping process

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

You flip a coin, and if the result is tails, you lose. If the result is heads, you get to play again. What is the expected value of throws before you lose?

**My Approach**

The expected value is the sum of all the outcomes multiplied by their respective probabilities:$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}V_iP_i$$So for this problem:$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i(\frac{1}{2^i})=0.5+0.5+0.375+…$$I can’t figure out how to find the sum, even though I know it converges.

Comment: This is the expectation of a geometric random variable. The probability of "success" is $p=0.5$, so the expected value is $1/p=2$.

Comment: It seems like your original problem has not much to do with the actual thought experiment popularly known as *Schroedinger's cat*. I have edited the post to avoid the misleading title (please feel free to modify it again to something more appropriate and which perhaps does not gratuitously mention harming animals...).

Comment: Yeah, thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an Arithmetic-Geometric Series. Let $S=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{i}{2^i}$. Then,
$$S=\displaystyle\frac {1}{2^1}+\frac {2}{2^2}+\frac{3}{2^3}+…+\frac{N}{2^N}.\tag{1}$$
Now, divide the whole equation by $2$ and arrange it by shifting the terms by a step: $$\frac{S}{2}=\frac {1}{2^2}+\frac {2}{2^3}+\frac{3}{2^4}+…+\frac{N-1}{2^{N}}+\frac{N}{2^{N+1}}.\tag{2}$$ $(1)-(2)$:$$\frac{S}{2}= \frac {1}{2^1}+\frac {1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+…+\frac{1}{2^N}+\frac{1}{2^{N+1}}.$$This is a G.P., so sum is $$\frac{S}{2}=\frac 12\left(\frac{1-\left(\frac12\right)^{N+1}}{1-\frac12}\right)$$$$\implies S =\left(\frac{1-\left(\frac12\right)^{N+1}}{1-\frac12}\right)$$ Taking an infinite sum gives us $S_{\infty}=2$, which is the required answer.

Answer (score 16):

In general, starting with a geometric series ($\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} x^j = 1/(1-x)$), you can evaluate many related series by taking derivatives or integrals.

- When you need to shift the exponent, multiply or divide by a power of $x$;
- When you need to multiply the coefficient by the exponent, take a derivative;
- When you need to divide the coefficient by the exponent, take an integral.

In this case,
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} j x^j=x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} x^{j}=x\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.
$$
Substituting $x=1/2$ gives $x/(1-x)^2=(1/2)/(1/2)^2=2.$

Comment: Note that ending in $j$ steps actually means $j-1$ non-fatal events plus one fatal one, which gives a probability of $x^{j-1}(1-x)$.

Comment: Yes, true.  This answer is about summing the series that OP correctly arrived at, not about the original coin-flipping problem.  So $x$ here shouldn’t be identified with $p$, the probability of flipping heads (though the same techniques could be used for the $p\neq 1/2$ case).

Answer (score 7):

A different perspective: If the first coin is T then it's lived for 1 minute, and if H, then you're repeating exactly the same process a minute later, so the time you should expect to wait is
$$x =  \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2}(x+1) \Rightarrow x=2$$